# Unable to forward external ssh port through router to raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, ssh

I am trying to expose my [raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com)'s ssh port to the world through my internet router.  I can connect to the device on my LAN.  I have another Windows 7 machine with cygwin and sshd installed on it and I can ssh  into that machine through my firewall.  I believe I know how to configure my router to forward ports.

Here's what I tried:

## Attempt 1

- Forward external port 22222 to port 22 on my raspbmc
- Connect to port 22222 on my external ip with:

  ```
  ssh -vv -p 22222 pi@MY_IP
  OpenSSH_6.2p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
  debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
  debug1: Connecting to MY_IP [MY_IP] port 22222.
  debug1: connect to address MY_IP port 22222: Connection timed out
  ssh: connect to host MY_IP port 22222: Connection timed out
  ```

  Doing this, but forwarding to my Win7 box works, seemingly indicating that I know how to configure my router.

## Attempt 2

Then I tried turning off port 22 forwarding to my Win7 machine and forwarding external port 22 to my rapsbmc's port 22, such that the only tweaking that I did of the router configuration was to change which LAN address the packets were forwarded to.  Connections to Win7 box stopped [expected], but connections to raspbmc did not work:

```
$ ssh -p 22 -vv pi@MY_IP
OpenSSH_6.2p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to MY_IP [MY_IP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address MY_IP port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host MY_IP port 22: Connection timed out
```

I believe the packets [UDP and TCP] are getting to my raspbmc from outside my LAN.  Where are the log files for `sshd` on raspbmc?  I can't even find sshd on my raspbmc:

```
 sudo find / -name sshd
```

yields nothing.

Comment: raspbmc uses dropbear and sshd.

Comment: It uses sshd, but only as a client I think. In this case only dropbear server matters.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I was facing the same problem. Please don't forget to forward the corresponding ports also in the router!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ugg.  I wasn't able to solve my own problem the other day, but when I typed out the question, then I got inspired to search the interwebs in a different way that [**yielded**](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6726) a [**solution**](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6850).  My issue was that [`iptables`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) is configured to block traffic that isn't on my [subnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).  You can test that this is the issue by running this command on your raspbmc:

```
sudo iptables --flush
```

If you're able to receive the ssh connections on your raspbmc now, then you need to tweak the `iptables` commands in `/etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc` such that it will not block non-subnet traffic:

```
logger -t iptables "Configuring ip tables for interface $IFACE"
if [ "$IFACE" != "lo" ]; then
    NETMASK=$(get_subnet $IFACE)
    iptables -A INPUT -s $NETMASK -i $IFACE -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP
fi
```

I commented out those lines with `#` using command `sudo vi /etc/network/if-up.d/secure-rmc`.  Those lines now look like:

```
#logger -t iptables "Configuring ip tables for interface $IFACE"
#if [ "$IFACE" != "lo" ]; then
#    NETMASK=$(get_subnet $IFACE)
#    iptables -A INPUT -s $NETMASK -i $IFACE -j ACCEPT
#    iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP
#fi
```

Then, when you reboot, it should be resolved.  This will make your raspbmc listening ports be wide open to accepting any packets from outside your network, for better or worse...

Comment: This is not the best solution I believe, why don't you open only the ports you need? add this line: "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT" before this line "iptables -A INPUT -i $IFACE -j DROP" and you're all set

Comment: I'll test that solution and update my answer when I can gain physical access to my raspmbc.  It's in my attic and it died last night...

Comment: Any idea of what went wrong?

Comment: I played a video.  Also my capacitor was broken off and my subsequent solder to the traces is pretty weak. My attic was hot yesterday, now it is cold.  No really sure. I'm just going to reboot it.