# RaspBMC SSH works from LAN but not from Internet?

Tags: raspbmc, ssh

I'm running RaspBMC on my Raspberry Pi connected to a router with the port `5555` forwarded to the `22` port on Raspberry Pi.

When I SSH to Raspberry Pi from LAN everything works, but I have troubles when I'm connecting to it remotely.

```
$ ssh myPublicIp -p5555 -v`
Connection timed out
```

I have no idea why port forwarding isn't working correctly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be an issue with your iptables, have a look at [this thread](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/unable-to-forward-external-ssh-port-through-router-to-raspbmc)

Comment: Are you using any firewalls?  Does your ISP block non-standard ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/unable-to-forward-external-ssh-port-through-router-to-raspbmc) from @Tim (Thanks!) my problem was solved by simple

```
sudo iptables --flush
```